# Woocommerce stock quantity and pending payment behaviour

Tags: woocommerce, stock

I will present a case I am having in my Woocommerce store. It is not an issue itself, but it is some behaviour I need to change.

When a client, let's say "Client A" makes a purchase but doesn't pay, the order remains in "Pending Payment" status. This status holds the stock but doesn't reduce it. Leading some cases where the stock available is not the real stock and affecting the user experience.

for example:
We have 10 units of "Product A" and the "Client A" order 5 units of that product and doesn't pay.

Then "Client B" see that "Product A" has 10 units in stock and adds 6 units or more to the cart. When goes to cart page a validation message appears and it says there are only 5 units in stock of "Product A". This happens because the "Pending payment" order of Client A is holding 5 units in stock. 10 - 5 = 5.

I think of two solutions for this matter:

1. Changing the behaviour of pending payment status so it reduces the stock instead of "holding it".
2. Changing the quantity stock number so it shows the actual stock minus the holding stock from Pending payment orders.

As far as I know this is a default behaviour of Woocommerce. What do you think I should do and how?

Thank you in advance.

I created a new woocommerce site without any other plugins and the behaviour it is the same.

Comment: Pending payment is abit confusing. This status should be used only with online payments where you expect payment right away. You should use either hold status or processing. Also setup auto cancel orders after x time from your settings.

Comment: Hi @MartinMirchev,this is happening when the client use Paypal. We expect the payment right away but some clients don't go to the end. We'r using On Hold and Processing status for different payment methods. We've also set up auto cancel orders but this matter is beyond that.
I believe we shouldn't force to change the status to On Hold cause that status is waiting the admins to take the next step but the client should continue and finish the payment. They need to have access to finish the purchase from their profile. To make this happen we need to remain the order in Pending Payment status.